# Richtext/CK editor is not working on Android

Tags: android, ckeditor, xpages, lotus-domino

I recently noticed that the standard richtext editor in xpages is not working on Android devices.

I have made a simple xpage with a single richtext field. When I view the page in iPhone on safari it works fine and also in chrome on Pc. But if I look in the device emulation in chrome most of the devices using android do not render the CK editor. Just a simple text area field is displayed.

I am using 9.0.1 FP2.

What do I need to do to get the CK editor to work on Android?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This is an issue in CKeditor itself it seems. It runs some code to determine if the detected browser is compatible with CKEditor based on the detected user-agent String. If that code returns false, CKEditor isn't loaded. This appears to be happening for any Android device using `v4.4` or later (including v5 and v6). There was a bug logged on their [tracking site](https://dev.ckeditor.com/ticket/13316). It looks like a fix was delivered to CKEditor `v4.5`. Currently `9.0.1FP5` uses CKEditor `v4.4.6`, before that fix was put in.

After looking at [this SQ question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30788527/ckeditor-4-4-7-does-not-show-up-on-any-mobile-browsers) I've implemented a workaround to get around the bug. Add the following script to your XPage to force CKEditor to load no matter what browser it detects:

```
<script><![CDATA[
    XSP.addOnLoad(function(){
       if( typeof(CKEDITOR) !== "undefined" ){ 
           CKEDITOR.env.isCompatible = true;
       }
    });]]>
</script>
```

You could even add that as a CSJS script library, and add that library to your theme, to ensure all instances of CKEditor throughout your app load on Android.

(Note that the linked SO question suggests a check to ensure CKEditor stays disabled on IE7 and older).

Comment: thanks Brian, that seem to work, but when I load the page in read mode I now get 
ReferenceError: CKEDITOR is not defined

Comment: I solved it: XSP.addOnLoad(function(){
 if( typeof(CKEDITOR) !== "undefined" ){
  CKEDITOR.env.isCompatible = true;
 }
})

Comment: thanks, will accept your answer as soon as my customer have verified that it is working